# Kinetic Energy of a system of ideal gas

Tags: kinetic-theory

For a nuclear fusion reaction in which goes as follows:

$${}^2_1H + {}^1_1p  \to {} ^3_2He + \gamma$$

If we assume that the mixture of deuterium nuclei and protons behave as an ideal gas, then can we say that they have equal amount of kinetic energies?

Comment: You would need another assumption (thermodynamic equilibrium) which can not be guaranteed while the reaction is going on without some additional assumptions (say requiring that the fusion rate be low as in most stars). Also you have two problems in your reaction expression: (a) the mass- and atomic-numbers on your hydrogen are wrong and (b) the product side should include a neutrino.

Answer (score 0):

Equipartition theorem can be used to arrive at your answer. Proton if treated as a point particle obviously has three degrees of freedom associated with translation giving 3/2 kT as the kinetic energy. The deuterium if treated as a point particle will have same kinetic energy  as the proton. However the structure of deuterium would result in considering it as made up of two point particle and this can lead to additional degrees of freedom associated with rotation and therefore higher kinetic energy than proton.